# Mangento MY PRODUCT REVIEWS showing You have submitted no reviews. even i had reviewed product

Tags: php, magento

Mangento MY PRODUCT REVIEWS showing You have submitted no reviews. even i had reviewed product.

Earlier it used to show i have added number of modules suddenly it stopped showing how can i debug as i have added 10 or more modules disbling them and checking one by one will be time wasting any easy workaround please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling 10 modules wouldn't take long (proabably less time than posting on SO!). And would be much quicker than trying to hunt through each one to find the cause.

Disable each one and see if it works. If it does enable them one by one, testing again after enabling each one. If it is a module that is causing the issue you will soon find it.
You can quickly disable modules in the local directory by placing this in the local.xml (in /app/etc dir)

```
 <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

Although this won't disable modules installed in the community directory.

Comment: ok i just worte <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
then it works, but when i disabled all modules from admin it is not working have i to uninstall modules to check

Comment: To disable a module, go to the app/etc/modules folder and find the module xml file. Edit that file and change true to false:     <active>false</active>. That will disable the module correctly. Then enable each one by changing it back to true.

Comment: problem is that even when user is logged in it's review shows in admin as guest review